# I can't ping my linux VM from any machine other then the windows host

Tags: linux, networking, beagleboneblack

I can ping my BBB on 192.168.1.166, which is the address my router gave it, and which I have since made static.

#### Windows host

Ip address: 192.168.1.219

#### My linux VM (running on windows host):

```
enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.102  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::dddc:91d0:276:c7b2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
```

#### BBB:

```
eth0: flags=-28605<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.166  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.7.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.7.255
```

I also tried to add a route, so my route table looks like:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.6.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 usb1
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 usb0
192.168.56.0    192.168.1.166   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0 <-- ADDED THIS
```

#### Summary

- From my linux VM I can ping my windows host and the BBB, both usb0 and eth0 (I can also ssh on to the BBB via both).
- From my windows host I can ping my linux VM and BBB (both addresses)
- from my BBB I can ping my windows host, but not my linux VM

I figure that this might have to do with my linux VM being on a different sub-net: 192.168.56.x, and not 192.168.1.x. So this is why I added a route in the table above.

What am I doing wrong?

#### UPDATE

I have another linux box on my network (192.168.1.120) and the BBB can ping that. However this second linux box also can't ping my linux VM - so I think the problem is anything that is not my windows host PC can't ping the linux VM... so the title to this question is now probably wrong and this is more of a "can't ping my linux VM" issue. Updating the title...

Comment: It is probably something to do with them being on different subnets, yes. Next question: **why** are they on different subnets? How is the VM's networking configured?

Comment: @user253751 - so I just updated my situation (see the update), but to answer your question "why"...err... not sure! I guess I can just change the VM to to be in the 192.168.1x range (virtualbox + ubuntu) - that might make things easier. But what confuses me is why my VM can ping/connect to everything else

Comment: So how is the VM's networking configured? I suspect you've got it in NAT mode, where the Windows host translates the IP addresses so that it looks like all the network traffic is coming from the Windows host. Try bridge mode, where the VM is allowed to connect directly to the network.

Comment: Yes you are right its configured as NAT and not bridged. I changed that and it all now just works. Note: I further confused things by pointing out the wrong IP address on my MV, that 192.168.56.102 on enp0s8 was the Host only port (for some file sharing between host/VM).  The enp0s3 is the one in use externally and that was set to 10.0.x.x (can't quite recall now). But once I configured as bridged network device the IP address of that adapter is 192.168.1.215 and all is well and I now understand what is going on.

Comment: @user253751 please feel free to add your comment as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you've got your VM set up in NAT mode, where the Windows host puts a fake network router in front of your VM, and translates the IP addresses so that it looks like all the network traffic is coming from the Windows host. This mode is used by default in some VM programs, because it's the most reliable, but it doesn't allow all networking features to work.

Try bridge mode, where the VM is allowed to connect directly to the network. It should join onto your home network like a real computer, and get an address in the 192.168.1 subnet from your home router.

Comment: thanks very much for your help